# Does the Facebook application has non-native features?

Tags: iphone, android, facebook, native

This is a very general question, i would solve it myself if i had a device on me.
Does the facebook app (for IPhone and similar question regarding the Android platform) has non-native features in it, or is it completely local, meaning operating entirely on the device?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "operating entirely" on the device. Facebook app needs to access the facebook.com to get all the data.

Comment: i mean exactly that. i know it needs to access data, the question is whether there are features that actually take us as users to on-line pages instead of native display, so that it is clear that we are now looking into information on the browser. Example - pressing on "friends" will take us to the safari browser to dsiplay the list of friends our profile has...

Comment: I'm not sure about the Android app, but iPhone app uses only Native Controls, nothing is shown as browser. I think it uses the Facebook API to grab the data and native controls/widgets to render the data.

Comment: OK, thanks Vijay. And what about the Android? Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

**Android**

The Native App is not redirecting you to the mobile version of the website.

The only exception I had found are event invitation messages that, when opened within the native app, will forward me to the website. I just checked again and links are not working anymore in messages when being received on the native client. Strange.

And if I may ask: Why? ;-)